# How we can characterize all positive integers, multiples of 4, that cannot be expressed as $(p_1-1)(p_2-1),\;\;p_1,\,p_2$ distinct primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

> I ask how we can characterize all positive integers
>   multiples of 4 that cannot be expressed as
>
> $(p_1-1)(p_2-1),\;\;p_1,\,p_2$ distinct primes

The first multiples of 4 that cannot be expressed as above are:

$68, 76, 124, 128, 152, 188, 236, 244, 248, 284, ...$

Integers of the following forms cannot be expressed:

$4(2+15m),\;\;m\ge 1$

$4(21m-4),\;\;m\ge 1$

$4(1+30m),\;\;m\ge 1$

Also asked in [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3685729/how-we-can-characterize-all-positive-integers-multiples-of-4-that-cannot-be-ex).

Many thanks.

Comment: It is unlikely that there's some nice characterization of these numbers.

Comment: Or in other words, multiples $n$ of $4$ such that for every divisor $d$ of $n$ with $d^2 \ne n$, $d+1$ or $n/d+1$ is composite.  But that's just a restatement of the condition.  The sequence is not in OEIS.

Comment: Its trivial that all numbers of the form $4p$, $p$ is a prime are in the sequence. Also it's trivial that the numbers which has less divisors are more likely to be in this sequence.